# MySQL Insert <--Unknown column 'nomePersona' in 'field list'' in

Tags: php, mysql, blob

Insert code:

```
INSERT INTO CalendarAppointment (`codiCategory`, `codiPersona`, `nomePersona`, `comment`, `day`, `description`, `from`, `shortDescription`, `to`, `modificatoDa`, `dataModifica`, `idModifica`) VALUES ('oUQz/ejwAfoAdAw7Jm+W1cFKeNH8N26ZBBcvhwwXPAA=', 'oUQz/ejwAfoAdAw7Jm+W1cFKeNH8N26ZBBcvhwwXPAA=', 'HuWZQyWSAnY9ReZ0q0+ZrBVRhReagvUG9Th1q3TtLPw=', 'q46vm3AsgJsEO6NOJ3r5xKhLMvvy+Sy05E76krKhiNo=', '2014-10-29', 'q46vm3AsgJsEO6NOJ3r5xKhLMvvy+Sy05E76krKhiNo=', '2014/10/13 09:00', 'q46vm3AsgJsEO6NOJ3r5xKhLMvvy+Sy05E76krKhiNo=', '2014/10/13 09:30', '2014-10-29 11:11:34', '2014-10-29 11:11:34', '1')
```

Show create table CalendarAppointment:

```
| CalendarAppointment | CREATE TABLE `CalendarAppointment` (  
`idAppointment` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `codiCategory` blob,
  `codiPersona` blob,
  `nomePersona` blob,
  `comment` blob,
  `day` datetime NOT NULL,
  `description` blob,
  `from` datetime NOT NULL,
  `shortDescription` blob,
  `to` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modificatoDa` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dataModifica` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `idModifica` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `idAppointment` (`idAppointment`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=104 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Using the exact code you posted, insert worked fine in my local mysql server.

Comment: after drop table and then create table all working